# Cruise Control.net doesn't copy rdlc files

Tags: asp.net, cruisecontrol.net, rdlc

I have a project which is pulled from svn and complied and copied to a server. This works out great for .NET code/Application, however the rdlc files that are in svn appear to be ignored. Any ideas?

Thanks Rob

Comment: How are you building the solution from CCNET?

Answer (score 1):

They will deploy.. All you have to do is bring up the properties of the file (f4) in your visual studio and then choose to copy to output directory and then choose "copy always"..